# Need to getElementById before div appears on the page

Tags: php, javascript, css, html, getelementbyid

I need to use a piece of javascript to find the current css style but before the div is opened.

My code is below: This works if I add it below the start of the actual div (slidingDiv)

However, I need it to work before the div as it will be used to control which button is shown. There will be a different button show depending on whether the div is shown or hidden.

Many thanks

Pete

```
<script>
if(document.getElementById('slidingDiv').style.display == 'none') alert('none');
else alert('show');
</script>
```

Comment: There is some problem with your logic. There must be some way around if you explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: You can't get a reference to something that does not yet exist. You should start with the div having `display: none` (or otherwise hide it at the start) and only show it when you have prepared it.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you need to write the JavaScript code block before the `<div>` appears in your source order, then defer the JavaScript by attaching it on `window.onload`:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (document.getElementById('slidingDiv').style.display == 'none') {
            alert('none');
        }
        else {
            alert('show');
        }
    };
</script>
<div id="slidingDiv"></div>
```

If you’re using jQuery then it’s even easier:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if ($('#slidingDiv').not(':visible')) {
            alert('none');
        }
        else {
            alert('show');            
        }
    });
</script>
<div id="slidingDiv"></div>
```

Although best practice is to place any and all JavaScript files at the bottom of your page so that your page loads the content first, then any progressive enhancement afterwards, otherwise your using is having to wait for the page to finish loading whilst you’re loading any fancy JavaScript effects.

Answer (score 0):

just hide both buttons in your css with "display: none;" put your code below your slidingDiv, and the buttons.

what you really should do, is to look for the dom to be ready (then you could put your javascript code everywhere - of course it should still be at the bottom of the page).

if you dont wnat to write the domready by yourself and dont want to include jquery in your page, there are pretty smart domready implementations, for example [this](https://github.com/ded/domready)

you would use it like that:

```
domready(function () {
  if (document.getElementById('slidingDiv').style.display == 'none') {
    alert('none');
  }
  else {
    alert('show');
  }
});
```

EDIT: 
to append stuff to your html, you could just set the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML)

```
domready(function () {
  var appendDiv = document.getElementById('someDivToAppend');
  if (document.getElementById('slidingDiv').style.display == 'none') {
    appendDiv.innerHTML('<p>hidden</p>');
  }
  else {
    appendDiv.innerHTML('<p>shown</p>');
  }
});
```

or you could use the [document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement), [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)-way

```
domready(function () {
  var appendDiv = document.getElementById('someDivToAppend')
    , newElement = document.createElement('div')

  if (document.getElementById('slidingDiv').style.display == 'none') {
    newElement.text = 'hidden';
  }
  else {
    newElement.text = 'shown';
  }
  appendDiv.appendChild(newElement);
});
```

use the [MDN-DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript)!

Comment: That's great! Works a treat. How do I print HTML instead of the alert?